# Is possible to pack a particular font in a WPF Program?

Tags: c#, wpf

For example, I want to pack this font:
http://www.dafont.com/mickeys-merry-xmas.font

I installed in my computer, and I want to change the font through fontFamily it doesn't appear, but if I modify that property in XAML it works. I don't know if this sittuation will be a problem.

Well, I only want to sure me that the program will run in everywhere with that font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it goes:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to pack the font as a resource in your WPF app, I'm not sure about that.  But it would be easier to just install the font with your application's installer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the font in your executable by adding it to the project, and set it to "Embedded Ressource" in the property window.

Also, Blend has a checkbox to specify that you want the font to be embedded in your program (which will do pretty much the same thing, only automatically).